# Image styles - not functioning properly after migration

Tags: media

I have just created a site serving as an online gallery. In the gallery the user can create an album and add images to this album.

Originally when I am working on my localhost the image styles are working properly - under each image styles drupal can create a proper subfolder with the same id of the album and save the image related to the album in it.

For example if I have created an album with the **node id 1** and uploaded an image named **123.jpg** to this album, it will save the styled image as the following: `styles/thumbnail/public/project/1/123.jpg`

After I have migrated to the remote server, drupal is still able to create different image styles for an image. However it is no longer creating subfolder for the albums or saving the styled images into subfolder. Instead everything is just saved in the public folder as the following `styles/thumbnail/public/123.jpg`.

I am worried that such malfunction on the remote server will affect the management of the site.  I have already tried to disable *clean urls*, changing the permissions of the folder to `775/777`.  However none of them seem to be the solution of this issue. How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to cooment out `Options None` and `Options +FollowSymLinks` in `.htaccess` in `sites/default/files/` ?

Comment: @Benone_ Yes I did. Unfortunately it is not working